# What do Chingón and Chinga mean?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, méxico

What is the difference between ***Chingón*** and ***Chinga***? Are they both bad words in Mexico?

Comment: I see you're trying to know about the meanings of different rude words last days. You should totally drop that and try jQuery.

Comment: La primera fuente de referencia para el significado de palabras es http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/drae

Comment: @Arkana Parece que quiere entrar en los carteles mexicanos, good for the JQuery idea...so StackOverflow

Comment: @Arkana I don't think what he was asking is that kind of advice. Rude words are part of a language as any other words, and who can tell another which kind of knowledge is good or bad for him?

Comment: @lorddarkangel aunque es cierto que el diccionario es la principal fuente de conocimiento, como podras darte cuenta con la respuesta de ["razpeitia"](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/4785/85) hay muchos otros usos que no estan documentados en el diccionario.

Comment: @AlfredoOsorio No te falta razón, pero no está de más recordar una fuente tan útil como el diccionario de la RAE. Puede aclarar futuras dudas de manera rápida y precisa, sin tener que pasar por aquí. Así se dejan las preguntas más complicadas para este sitio.

Comment: @lorddarkangel [¿Estan dentro del alcance del sitio las preguntas que piden el significado de una palabra?](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/327/estan-dentro-del-alcance-del-sitio-las-preguntas-que-piden-el-significado-de-un)

Comment: @derpolyglot33 do you even have a criterion to accept  answers? I'm really curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Chingar** es el verbo. Usualmente significa molestar o fastidiar. Pero puede tener otros significados como fornicar.

**Chingón o Chingona** es el adjetivo. Si es aplicado a una persona significa que la persona es muy hábil en lo que sea que estén hablando. Si es aplicado a un objeto significa que el objeto es de muy buena calidad.

**Chingo** sustantivo cuantitativo para expresar grandes cantidades.

**Chinga** puede tener dos significados, que a alguien le dieron una paliza o que algo fue exhaustivo.

**Chingado o Chingada** puede ser un adjetivo y significar que algo esta dañado. O puede también ser un lugar.

**Chingadazo** sinónimo de golpe.

## Ejemplos

**Chingar**

*Vete a chingar a tu madre.* (Aquí ambos significados pueden estar correctos)

**Chingón**

*Pero que vieja mas chingona.* (Aplicado a persona)

*Esta cámara esta chingona.* (Aplicado a objeto)

**Chingo**

*Esta computadora cuesta un chingo* (Esta computadora cuesta mucho)

**Chinga**

*Hoy me lleve una chinga en el trabajo* (El trabajo estuvo muy duro hoy)

*A mi hermano le pusieron una chinga por meterse con la novia de Juan* (Le dieron una paliza a mi hermano por meterse con la novia de Juan)

**Chingado**

*El carro esta chingado* (El carro esta dañado)

*Vete mucho a la chingada* (Como un lugar)

*Hijo de la chingada* (Como madre en algunos casos)

**Chingadazo**

*Y entonces le metí un chingadazo*

Como puedes ver hay un chingo de situaciones donde dependiendo del contexto puede significar una u otra cosa.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta. Solo falta agregar tambien el uso de dañado como "se chingo" Ejemplo: El carro se chingó (dejo de funcionar). Tambien "Él/ella se chingó" o "ya te chingaste" es que él/ella/tú están en problemas.

Answer (score 5):

Octavio Paz en su libro *El Laberinto de la Soledad* hace un pequeño análisis de esta palabra y su signnificado, no sólo en México, sino no en otras partes de América Latina. Un fragmento de ese texto dice:

> En México los significados de la palabra son innumerables. Es una voz mágica. Basta un cambio de tono, una inflexión apenas, para que el sentido varíe. Hay tantos matices como entonaciones: tantos significados como sentimientos. Se puede ser un chingón, un Gran Chingón (en los negocios, en la política, en el crimen, con las mujeres), un chingaquedito (silencioso, disimulado, urdiendo tramas en la sombra, avanzando cauto para dar el mazazo), un chingoncito. Pero la pluralidad de significaciones no impide que la idea de agresión en todos sus grados, desde el simple de incomodar, picar, zaherir, hasta el de violar, desgarrar y matar se presente siempre como significado último. El verbo denota violencia, salir de sí mismo y penetrar por la fuerza en otro. Y también, herir, rasgar, violar cuerpos, almas, objetos, destruir.

Aquí el [texto](http://www.lainsignia.org/2007/julio/cul_009.htm) completo.

Comment: Una pena que ésta no sea la respuesta aceptada.

Comment: @c.p. Sí. Encuentro difícil dar una mejor explicación de la palabra "chingar" y sus significados que la que hizo Octavio Paz.

Answer (score 0):

Chingón es un sustantivo, su significado es: http://dle.rae.es/ching%C3%B3n
Chinga puede ser un verbo o un adjetivo, su significado es: http://dle.rae.es/chinga

Ambas son malsonantes.

Comment: *Chingón* no (sólo) es un sustantivo. Y DRAE no dice que en México *chinga* sea un adjetivo.

Comment: Me han dicho que 'chinga', como verbo, significa 'molesta' en espa~na y no es una mala palabra allí.

Comment: `chinga` como verbo puede ser molestar, joder...ej: chinga a tu madre...como que me dejes en paz y vayas a joder a tu madre, chingon como adjetivo es indicar que la persona es jodedora, que siempre esta dando dolores de cabezas...ej: fulano es un chingon