# ¿Qué quiere decir "bancado" o "bancadísimo" en Argentina?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, coloquialismos, argentina

Leo [un tuit](https://twitter.com/Fglamas/status/1008719573326159872) de un periodista argentino en el que enlaza el vídeo de una entrevista a Chicharito, un jugador de fútbol mexicano. Al comentario del entrevistador *Pongámonos serios, México no está para ser campeón del mundo*, sigue lo que indica el tuit en sí:

> — ¿Por qué no podemos ser Grecia en la Eurocopa o Leicester en la Premier?
>   —Porque Alemania está en el grupo. Lo tiene asegurado.
>   —¡Pero imaginemos cosas chingonas! ¿Por qué quedarnos?
>
> Bancadísimo Chicharito.

Para poner contexto en el tema: el vídeo toma relevancia ahora, cuando México ganó a Alemania en su primer partido. Por tanto, y si lo entiendo bien, esas *cosas chingonas* a las que se refieren son pequeñas utopías que al paso de los días se han convertido en reales.

Volviendo a lo estrictamente lingüístico, vemos una mezcla interesante de regionalismos: por un lado está lo de [*cosas chingonas*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/4773/1674) mexicano, que ya conozco. Por el otro, está el *bancadísimo* argentino, que no conocía y es a lo que voy.

A mí me parece que con *bancadísimo* está queriendo decir *valiente*, *iluminado* o cualquier cosa del estilo. Sin embargo, busco y busco en el DAMER y me encuentro con definiciones que no me acaban de encajar:

> [**bancar(se)**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=bancar).
>
> I.    1.  tr. Bo, Ar, Ur. Mantener una persona económicamente a alguien. pop + cult → espon.
>   2.  tr. prnl. Bo, Ur; Ar, pop. Asumir la responsabilidad de un dicho o una situación.
>   3.  tr. Ar, Ur. Pagar los gastos de alguien en una salida común, especialmente en un lugar de diversión. pop + cult → espon.
>
> II.   1.  tr. Bo, Ar, Ur; Ch, p.u. Tolerar, soportar a alguien o algo. pop + cult → espon.
>   2.  Bo, Ar, Ur. Apoyar o ayudar una persona a alguien.

Así como *bancado* en el DLE:

> [**bancar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4wZaf6M)
>   `De banca.`
>
> 1. tr. coloq. Arg. y Ur. Mantener o respaldar a alguien.
>
> 2. tr. coloq. Arg. y Ur. Soportar, aguantar a alguien o algo. *A ese pesado no lo banca nadie*. U. t. c. prnl. *No se banca las críticas.*
>
> 3. tr. Ur. En una salida colectiva, pagar los gastos de alguien.
>
> 4. prnl. coloq. Arg. Responsabilizarse de algo que se ha dicho o hacerse cargo de una situación. *Yo me banco lo que digo.*

¿Qué quiere decir "bancado" pues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Bancadísimo Chicharito* ➡ *Banco mucho a Chicharito*

Se trata de la primera acepción del DLE. El autor del tuit está diciendo que apoya totalmente la actitud de Chicharito. Es el significado más común de *bancar* en Argentina.

Comment: Caramba, qué forma curiosa de decir _banco a X_